# What does it mean to say that an object complement describes the object?

Tags: adverbs, object-complements

> She cut the paper gingerly.

> She cut him loose.

*gingerly* above is an adverb but *loose* isn't.

This is because *gingerly* describes the manner of "her" cutting the paper, but loose doesn't do so.

> What does it mean to say that *loose* is an object complement? By definition, an *object complement* describes the object. Does it mean that in the sentence above it tells us how the person was after being *cut loose?* In other words, does the *object complement* tell us that the person was free after being *cut loose*?

Comment: You could say a person was ***free** after being set/cut **loose***. But you couldn't say he was ***loose** after being set/cut **free*** - in that case, you'd have to say he was ***on the loose***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers— Thanks a lot! Could you please parse the sentence for me? Is _loose_ an object complement here or is the phrase _cut loose_ an implied PP as another member has noted (Unfortunately, I couldn't follow that argument.)

Comment: That comment was the best I could do, I'm afraid. Note that I have little interest in the relevant *terminology* for things like this. Things like nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs are useful terms when the categorisation is easy, but as soon as it becomes difficult to decide *which* "Party of Speech" applies to some usage, I would generally consider that to be a strong indicator that such categorisation isn't useful for the context anyway).

Comment: Yes. It's an idiom meaning to free someone or something from something which holds or restricts them. I think it's better to classify it as a resultative objective complement rather than as a manner adjunct.

Comment: cut loose is not only an idiom. It is much easier to understand these if you examine the implied absences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers— Much obliged, Sir! Your comments are always helpful.

Comment: @BillJ: Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to cut loose** is an idiomatic expression.

She cut him loose. suggests she **let him go** as a boyfriend or lover. She cut off his "attachment" to her.

Also, **it can be literal**. She cut him loose [from the rope around his wrists.]

It implies that a person is attached to something. The attachment can be emotional or literal and the ties or bonds are not always given in the metaphor but always implied.

It is a phrasal verb: to cut someone loose [break off a relationship with them]
In literal contexts, the ties are there.

to cut the paper gingerly = to cut the paper cautiously or carefully.

In short, to **cut loose** means to removes the ties that literally or metaphorically **bind** or **tie** a person to another or to something and it can be used as a phrasal verb.

**set free** and **cut loose** are **phrasal or two-words verbs** with implied prepositional phrases, which explains how they became phrasal verbs.

to be set free [**from a cage**]
to be cut loose [**from attachments**, literally or not]

Comment: Thank you, @Lambie. But I'm more interested in the grammar of the sentence here. In its literal sense, _loose_ is an object complement because it describes the pronoun "him" (after being freed), i.e., "he was set free"?

Comment: set free is also phrasal: to be set free [from something or someone]. Same thing. There is an implied prepositional phrase, just like cut loose. loose and free are not object complements.

Comment: _prepositional phrase_? How so?

Comment: I just told you that: to be set free [**from something**] "**from a cage" is a prepositional phrase**.

Comment: —  Ok i got that now. Thanks. But an idiom is parseable still, right? Here it's something like this: Subject+ transitive verb+ object+ adjective? +implied PP. Is that right?

Comment: For me, it's:  Subject + phrasal verb. OR Subject + two-word verb. That said, if you prefer the grammar touted by "those above", that's up to you. Personally, I think it confuses things as it does not **clarify** the implied prepositional phrase which is beautifully logical in English and makes everything very clear regarding meaning.

Comment: I get your point @Lambie. Thanks a lot for a superb answer! :)